# Warning: A non-numerical value encountered in CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution

Tags: contributions

Why did I get this warning when entering contribution?

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::calculateMissingAmountParams() (line 383 of /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php).

CiviCRM 5.11 on Drupal.

I clicked on **New Contribution** in the menu and then entered a cash contribution.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuB9t.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v1oZ.png]

The problem also exists on CiviCRM Sandbox server
dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

[image]

Comment: Can you add CiviCRM version? And also some steps to replicate the bug

Comment: Could you see if the problem exists on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org?  If not, then this is likely to be a bug that's been fixed in a newer version - or perhaps is related to an extension you have installed?

Comment: Yes, the problem does exist on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org.
See edit of main post.